# Prestashop attributes

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to add product with many attributes in Prestashop (more then 4 select fields and each of them has 100 variants). But in the end it turns out that creates a lot of combinations (100^4=100000000 combination). How can I make an attributes without creating combinations? Make them independent from each other?

Comment: the product price is related to attributes? also you can , instead of attributes, use features http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Product+Features

Comment: No price not related on the attributes. Just make a choice when buying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/attribute-modules/34-attribute-wizard-pro.html

New version of this module support creating attributes without creating combinations

Or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Features is not the way, with them you can't chose anything when buy,
if you don't want use attributes and relative combinations try this free module, you can add some accessories at yours product

http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/prestashop-free-modules/33-product-accessories.html